# What does Lor San Tekka mean when he says "Something far worse has happened to you"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* what does the Lor San Tekka mean by saying "Far worse happened to you"?

[image: Lor San Tekka speaks to Kylo Ren in the foreground saying the above quote, in the background the Stormtroopers surround the villagers and the village is on fire]

Is it the fact that Kylo Ren has turned to the dark side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's relevant that the full text of the exchange is:

> **Ren:** Look how old you've become.
>
> **Tekka:** Something far worse has happened to you.
>
> <sup>*The Force Awakens* (2015)</sup>

In context, Ren and Tekka are comparing how they have changed since their last meeting. Tekka is unquestionably referring to Ren falling to the Dark Side, joining the Knights of Ren, massacring Luke's other Jedi students, and generally becoming a cruel and cold-hearted person.

We can compare this to a similar exchange in the original film:

> **Vader:** When I left you, I was but a learner; now I am the master.
>
> **Obi-Wan:** Only a master of evil, Darth.
>
> <sup>*A New Hope* (1977)</sup>

Here Obi-wan is denigrating Vader's fall to the Dark Side, suggesting that it has weakened him, or at least not strengthened him as much as he thinks. Ren tries to do something similar to Tekka, pointing out his age and (by implication) frailty. Tekka's response does the same as Obi-wan's, above; implying that Ren has lessened himself by falling to the Dark Side.

Answer (score 1):

He was referring to Kylo Ren's transition to the dark side of the Force.

> The passenger from the shuttle stared at Tekka, examining him from
> head to foot much as one would a relic in a museum. Tekka gazed back
> evenly. **The black mask, with its slitted forehead and thick, snoutlike
> breathing apparatus, covered the face of the man he knew as Kylo Ren.
> Once, he had known the face behind the mask. Once, he had known the
> man himself. Now, to San Tekka, only the mask was left. Metal instead
> of man.**
>
> Ren spoke first, without hesitation, as if he had anticipated this
> meeting for some time. “The great soldier of fortune. Captured at
> last.” **Though emanating from a human throat, the voice that was
> distorted by the mask had the sick flavor of the disembodied.**
>
> Tekka had expected no less. **“Whereas something far worse has happened
> to you.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>